# Changing file type Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip

I have an existing Paperclip setup that converts all uploaded images to JPG's. However, I've noticed that PNG's and GIF's uploaded and converted to JPG's end up with a strange colors and some kind of in-versing effect. I know JPG's don't support transparency, but I've recently found the need to accept PNG's and GIF's and not convert them to JPG...

My current config:

```
has_attached_file :icon,
                  :styles => { :featured => ["330x90>", :jpg], :thumb => ["48x48>", :jpg] },
                  :convert_options => { :all => "-quality 95" },
                  :path => "media/nation_apps/content_sources/:id/icon_:style.:extension"
```

When I removed the :jpg key it broke all existing uploads. How can I change my paperclip setup to not force JPG conversion but still work with all of my previously uploaded attachments?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the key then using

`rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=User`

Which will regenerate all your images.
Make sure you replace the class with the correct one for your app.
See this link on [thumbnail generation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation) for more info.